# Ajax URL Path not Replacing current URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

get a problem with ajax url. 
Here's the code:

```
 onConfirm: function(){
        var id = $(".branchid").data('id');
        var url = "view-merchants-branch/" + id;
        console.log(url);   

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: {_method: "DELETE", id:id},
            success: function() {
                alert("Data has been deleted");
                location.reload();

            },
            error: function(){
                console.log(url)
            }
        });

    },
    onCancel: function(){
        return;
    }
```

my url not replacing the current url and its become 404.

the result is:
     http://localhost/admin/public/view-merchants/9/view-merchants-branch/273

expected result is:
     http://localhost/admin/public/view-merchants-branch/273

I've tried change the type to "DELETE" but still no hope.
is there wrong with my ajax?. as i know ajax url will replace current url.

Comment: You are using relative URL. change it to absolute URL.

Comment: try  var url = "admin/view-merchants-branch/" + id;

Comment: @Satpal i've tried this way on my update data it works. thats why i dont find the solutiion. any solution?

Comment: @AyyanarG i've tried your way. it still not replacing the url. http://localhost/admin/public/view-merchants/9/dmadmin/view-merchants-branch/273

Comment: var url = "../../view-merchants-branch/" + id;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
url: '<?php echo "http://" .$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/admin/public/";>'+url,
 type: "POST",
```

Comment: this works. i'm curious i used url directly at update. it can get into it.

Comment: this code also help yu how to use php code inside in script tag

Comment: yes. it helps a lot.

If u dont mind would you mind to explain at update i just use url like above and it works. but not at delete

Comment: $('#merchantupdate').click(function(){
  
  var id = $("#merchant_id").val();
  var url = "view-merchants-branch/" + id;
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: url,
   dataType: "json",
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
   success: function(data)
   {
    console.log(success);
   },
   error: function(data)
   {
    console.log(data);
   }

  });
  
 });

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74689/discussion-between-satish-rajak-and-sstarlight).

Answer (score 0):

Check your network requests to see how the url is constructed,
Also visit this link to get better understanding about how ajax works
http://www.sitepoint.com/use-jquerys-ajax-function/

also this link
https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/key-concepts/#ajax-and-firebug

Answer (score 0):

Hi instead pass absolute url like,

```
onConfirm: function(){
    var id = $(".branchid").data('id');
    var url = SITE_URL+"view-merchants-branch/" + id;//SITE_URL IS GLOBAL VARIABLE,WHICH IS ABSOLUTE PATH  COMES UPTO http://localhost/admin/public/
    console.log(url);
```